# Is there a more efficient way to add and remove classes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

Is there a more efficient way to add and remove classes in jQuery? I was thinking about using .toggle(), but it looks like it's only being used to show/hide only. Oh yeah, the code below works perfectly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#inputResidenceHalls").click(function() {
        $("#residenceHallsForm").removeClass("hide");
        $("#residenceHallsForm").addClass("animated bounceInLeft");
        $("#inputApartments").click(function() {
            $("#residenceHallsForm").addClass("hide");
            $("#residenceHallsForm").removeClass("animated bounceInLeft");
        });
    });
    $("#inputApartments").click(function() {
        $("#apartmentsForm").removeClass("hide");
        $("#apartmentsForm").addClass("animated bounceInRight");
        $("#inputResidenceHalls").click(function() {
            $("#apartmentsForm").addClass("hide");
            $("#apartmentsForm").removeClass("animated bounceInRight");
        });
    });
});
```

Let me know if you guys have any questions.

Thanks guys! I really appreciate it.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: you can chain instead of writing stuff like $("#apartmentsForm") twice...

Comment: You're rebinding redundant handlers on every click. This needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`removeClass` and `addClass` both return the jQuery object, so rather than repeating the selector you can just keep chaining:

```
$("#inputResidenceHalls").click(function() {
    $("#residenceHallsForm").removeClass("hide").addClass("animated bounceInLeft");
    $("#inputApartments").click(function() {
        $("#residenceHallsForm").addClass("hide").removeClass("animated bounceInLeft");
    });
});
$("#inputApartments").click(function() {
    $("#apartmentsForm").removeClass("hide").addClass("animated bounceInRight");
    $("#inputResidenceHalls").click(function() {
        $("#apartmentsForm").addClass("hide").removeClass("animated bounceInRight");
    });
});
```

});

Comment: OP is redundantly binding handlers every time there's a click. This needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Well instead of removing the class you can just:

```
$("#residenceHallsForm").attr('class', 'animated bounceInRight');
```

This will remove all other classes and only the classes listed will be assigned to that ID.

However; 'TOGGLE' works fine aswell for classes just as with show hide.

Answer (score 0):

```
var $inputResidenceHalls = $("#inputResidenceHalls");

$inputResidenceHalls.click(function() {
    $inputResidenceHalls.toggleClass("hide animated bounceInLeft");
    $("#inputApartments").click(function() {
        $inputResidenceHalls.toggleClass("hide animated bounceInLeft");
    });
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Comment: On a side note - repeatedly selecting elements from the document is really bad from a performance standpoint, if you are ever selecting the same element `$('#foo').doSomething(); $('#foo').doSomething();` you most likely should be storing it in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use `.toggleClass()` function to add/remove class.
Here is the explanation [link](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

Comment: ups, @papirtiger just barely made it faster than me :)